# How to get a wasm stacktrace

Tags: clang, webassembly, emscripten

I'm looking for something gdb --core equivalent on webassembly.

Take this example:

```cpp
//crash.cpp
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                             
int main() {                                                                                                                                                                    
    std::cout << "crashing soon..." << std::endl;                                                                                                                                          
    int *a = 0;                                                                                                                                                                 
    *a = 1;                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

I compile this with:

```sh
$ em++ -g4 crash.cpp -o crash.html --source-map-base http://localhost:8080/
```

And start the server:

```sh
$ emrun --no_browser --port 8080 crash.html
```

So how can I get a stack trace of this core dump/crash? The console on both chrome/firefox when visiting page just shows a js stacktrace and that won't help me. Looking at Sources => Call stack on chrome console just shows "Not paused", after the crash.
This is on debian 11, emscripten 2.0.12~dfsg-2, clang-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that what you're doing is not an error in WebAssembly. Like on many embedded platforms, writing to or reading from zero pointer is a perfectly valid operation in WebAssembly memory model.

However, Emscripten tries to help you catch this as for C/C++ it's a common mistake, so what it does instead is checks the value at the address zero *after* the program has finished execution and throws a helpful assertion if that value happened to be overwritten. For this reason you're getting a stacktrace with only JavaScript bits in it - because the check is done by JavaScript when Wasm stack has already been exited.

If you tried a different operation that does cause immediate abort, for example, `assert(false)`, then you would see WebAssembly and/or C/C++ on the stack as expected.